# Custom optional class not deallocating when assigned to nil

Tags: ios, swift

Following Apple's book on Swift, I run into a problem when it comes to deinitializers. The code from the book makes a struct and a class, the struct `Bank` keeps track of coins (never having less than 0 or more than 10,000), while the class `Player` represents a player that owns coins from the bank.

```
struct Bank
{
    static var coinsInBank = 10_000
    static func vendCoins(var numberOfCoinsToVend: Int) -> Int
    {
        numberOfCoinsToVend = min(numberOfCoinsToVend, coinsInBank)
        coinsInBank -= numberOfCoinsToVend
        return numberOfCoinsToVend
    }
    static func recieveCoins(coins: Int)
    {
        coinsInBank += coins
    }
}

class Player
{
    var coinsInPurse: Int
    init(coins: Int)
    {
        coinsInPurse = Bank.vendCoins(coins)
    }
    func winCoins(coins: Int)
    {
        coinsInPurse += Bank.vendCoins(coins)
    }
    deinit
    {
        Bank.recieveCoins(coinsInPurse)
    }
}
```

The problem is, when the `Player` class is set to `nil`, Apple's book says that Swift should automatically deallocate it. The `deinit` should return all coins from `Player` to `Bank`, but it doesn't according to the code testing it:

```
var playerOne: Player? = Player(coins: 100)
println("A new player has joined the game with \(playerOne!.coinsInPurse) coins") // Prints "A new player has joined the game with 100 coins"

println("There are \(Bank.coinsInBank) coins left in the bank") // Prints "There are 9900 coins left in the bank"

playerOne?.winCoins(2_000)
println("PlayerOne won 2000 coins and now has \(playerOne!.coinsInPurse) coins") // Prints "PlayerOne won 2000 coins and now has 2100 coins"

println("The bank now only has \(Bank.coinsInBank) coins") // Prints "The bank now only has 7900 coins"

playerOne = nil
println("PlayerOne has left the game") // Prints "PlayerOne has left the game"

println("The bank now has \(Bank.coinsInBank) coins") // Prints "The bank now has 7900 coins"
```

I don't know if the code isn't properly deinitializing the class.

Comment: FWIW, tried this by copypasting directly into a Swift playground in XCode 7 Beta 4, changed the `println`s to `print` (as per Swift 2 rename), and the last statement printed `10000` for the bank. So it would seem that nothing is wrong with the code shown here.

Comment: Tried with XCode 6.4 as well, also printed `10000` in the last statement. Just to be sure it's not a problem somewhere else, try pasting the code into an otherwise completely empty playground.

Comment: The object will be released and the de-initialiser will be called *eventually*. It won't happen during the execution of a function due to the cost of the context switch which is why you don't see the correct balance immediately after assigning nil.

Comment: So basically swift is just waiting for the memory to be needed to deinitialize the Player class? @Paulw11

Comment: No, nil removes the reference and once the reference count is 0 ARC will release the object, but you can't expect it to happen instantaneously. Certainly not in the middle of a function execution.

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: no.

About ARC:

> Swift uses Automatic Reference Counting (ARC) to track and manage your app’s memory usage. In most cases, this means that memory management “just works” in Swift, and you do not need to think about memory management yourself. ARC automatically frees up the memory used by class instances when those instances are no longer needed.

About Deinitializers:

> Deinitializers are called automatically, just before instance deallocation takes place. You are not allowed to call a deinitializer yourself. Superclass deinitializers are inherited by their subclasses, and the superclass deinitializer is called automatically at the end of a subclass deinitializer implementation. Superclass deinitializers are always called, even if a subclass does not provide its own deinitializer.
>   In plain English:

You cannot rely on **ARC** to deallocate your objects synchronously. Reducing the count to 0 is by no mean the equivalent of **C++** `free()`.